# how can I split a large image into small pieces in python

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network

I need to create 30 * 30 px small images from splitting a large image.  I need  these parts separately saved in separate files after being split up like so:

[image: i need these parts separately saved in separate files]

Comment: And you have tried.. what?

Comment: Is your goal to cut the image up or to use Python to do it ?

Comment: i want to cut a large image into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
for r in range(0,img.shape[0],30):
    for c in range(0,img.shape[1],30):
        cv2.imwrite(f"img{r}_{c}.png",img[r:r+30, c:c+30,:])
```

Comment: This cuts a single part.
but what i want is to cut the image into multiple smaller parts.
for example i need 1000 * 1000 px image cut into 30 * 30 pix images and save them in separate files.

Comment: Did you try it really?

Comment: sorry brother. its working. i was too hurry. 
Many thanks for helping me

Comment: It's only 4 lines of codes and guaranteed to work correctly. You test if `img = cv2.imread('image.png')` loads correctly. Remember to replace `image.png` with (absolute path to) your image name.

Comment: @Sahan - if it's working you might accept this answer as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86978).

Comment: How to combine it as 1 image again?

Answer (score 4):

Try use image_slicer. (8 x 8 from your description)

```
import image_slicer

image_slicer.slice('C:\\files\\cars.png', 64)
```

This' how the outputs looked like.

[image]